How to deploy .NET 7 app to subfolder in IIS
I'm trying to deploy a newly created .NET 7 web API to a server in a subdirectory so that I can access it at https://example.com/my_api
This is my first .NET 7 deployment. All my older Webforms apps were able to be deployed by right clicking the folder in IIS and selecting "Convert to Application" and then making sure I have the right app pool selected.

That doesn't appear to be working. I can successfully deploy it as a whole new website (which tells me I've installed the hosting bundle correctly and am using the right app pool), but that requires me to access it at https://example.com:12345 which is isn't very friendly.
Sure, I could probably set up some sort of redirect or alternate domain that points users to the correct port but it would be ideal if the "Convert to Application" option worked as expected and this app could live side-by-side with the rest of my apps.
Is there something I need to do differently with .NET 7/.NET Core to get this working?
Thanks!

The "Convert to Application" method is feasible. Did you encounter any problem or error when it didn't work? go to the IIS -> right click your website -> create the virtual directory with the name of my_api -> right click the virtual directory my_api and select Convert to Application.

@samwu - I'm just getting a 404 error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

While I'm still not 100% what the issue was, I ended up upgrading the project from .NET 7 to 8 and deploying to a different server and I was able to Convert to Application as expected. I assume that means the issue was either with IIS or some bug related to .NET 7.

The following are some common causes of 404 error message, you can check it

The requested file has been renamed.
The requested file has been moved to another location and/or deleted.
The requested file is temporarily unavailable due to maintenance, upgrades, or other unknown causes.
The requested file does not exist.
The appropriate Web service extension or MIME type is not enabled.
A virtual directory is mapped to the root of a drive on another server.

